# Swing: Panel Size Issue

Tags: java, swing, layout, panel, layout-manager

I am designing an application, in which there should be 5 different `JPanel`s containing different **Swing components**. For the `JRadioButton` part, I ran into an issue for which couldn't find proper solution. The 'radioSizePanel' is supposed to be placed somewhere in upper middle of the main panel. Has anyone solved this problem before ? Here is the code, that I am using :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PizzaShop extends JFrame 
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JRadioButton[] radio_size = new JRadioButton[3];
    private JRadioButton[] radio_type = new JRadioButton[3];
    public PizzaShop() 
    {
        initializaUI();
    }

    private void initializaUI()
    {
        setSize(700, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Panel container to wrap checkboxes and radio buttons
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        //sizes radio buttons
        String Size[] = {"Small: $6.50", "Medium: $8.50", "Large: $10.00"};
        JPanel radioSizePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        ButtonGroup radioSizeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            radio_size[i] = new JRadioButton(Size[i]);
            radioSizePanel.add(radio_size[i]);
            radioSizeGroup.add(radio_size[i]);
        }
        radioSizePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(), "Size"));
        radioSizePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 200));

        //
        panel.add(radioSizePanel);
        setContentPane(panel);
        setContentPane(radioSizePanel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                new PizzaShop().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is what I want as an expected OUTPUT :

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

Comment: `frame.setContentPane()`, simply adds a `JPanel` as the `Content Pane`. Now you had written that thing twice, so that last added `radioSizePanel`, will be the one which will hide the `panel`. May you please write the layout on a paper and take it's snap and post it with your question, as to what you want as an expected output of the view ?

Comment: Sure, I have an image of my expected layout, could you tell me how could I post it here so you can see?

Comment: I'm not allowed to upload images here as I need to earn reputation! Is there any other way to demonstrate my Layout? :(

Comment: Put that on any site like [4shared](http://www.4shared.com/) or [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/) and put the link here, then I will edit the post to add that snap to the question or someone else will do that :-) Now you need 2 more points I guess

Comment: here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cbk41hxo8ygy00n/layout.jpg

Comment: Thanks @GagandeepBali, your first hint gave me the clue as the components has appeared into my panel. But the problem is setBound() function does not work as I want to locate them in particular positions in the frame.

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-). I am working on your stuff now, trying to place components, soon as I get something usefull to present, I will post that as an answer. To be true, you shouldn't use anything like `setBounds()/setXxXSize()` on any components. This is a work of the LayoutManager, let it handle for you, instead of you taking that pain on yourself.

Comment: Thanks, You're making me cry :), hope you'd help me with ActionListener and stuff, mainly the background system of this pain in the neck GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Please do watch the code example and Please do watch everything carefully , the sequence of adding things to the `JFrame`. Since in your example you calling `setSize()` much before something has been added to the `JFrame`, hence first add components to the container, and then call it's `pack()/setSize()` methods, so that it can realize that in a good way.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PizzaLayout
{
    /*
     * Five JPanels we will be using.
     */
    private JPanel headerPanel;
    private JPanel footerPanel;
    // This JPanel will contain the middle components.
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JPanel toppingPanel;
    private JPanel sizePanel;
    private JPanel typePanel;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;

    private String[] toppings = {
                                    "Tomato",
                                    "Green Pepper",
                                    "Black Olives",
                                    "Mushrooms",
                                    "Extra Cheese",
                                    "Pepproni",
                                    "Sausage"
                                };

    private JCheckBox[] toppingsCBox;

    private String[] sizePizza = {
                                    "Small $6.50", 
                                    "Medium $8.50",
                                    "Large $10.00"
                                 };

    private JRadioButton[] sizePizzaRButton;

    private String[] typePizza = {
                                    "Thin Crust", 
                                    "Medium Crust",
                                    "Pan"
                                 };

    private JRadioButton[] typePizzaRButton;

    private JButton processButton;

    private ButtonGroup bGroupType, bGroupSize;

    private JTextArea orderTArea;

    private StringBuilder sBuilderOrder;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pizza Shop");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        /*
         * This JPanel is the base of all the
         * other components, and at the end 
         * we will set this as Content Pane
         * for the JFrame.
         */
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        contentPane.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        /*
         * TOP PART of the LAYOUT.
         */
        headerPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel(
                "Welcome to Home Style Pizza Shop"
                                    , JLabel.CENTER);
        headerLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        headerPanel.add(headerLabel);

        /*
         * CENTER PART of the LAYOUT.
         */
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        gbc.weightx = 0.3;
        gbc.weighty = 1.0;

        /*
         * Above Constraints are for this part.
         */
        toppingPanel = new JPanel();
        toppingPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED),
                                            "Each Topping $1.50"));
        JPanel checkBoxesPanel = new JPanel();
        checkBoxesPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        checkBoxesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));

        toppingsCBox = new JCheckBox[toppings.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < toppings.length; i++)
        {
            toppingsCBox[i] = new JCheckBox(toppings[i]);
            checkBoxesPanel.add(toppingsCBox[i]);
        }

        toppingPanel.add(checkBoxesPanel);
        centerPanel.add(toppingPanel, gbc);

        // Till this.

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0.7;

        /*
         * Above Constraints are for this part.
         */
        sizePanel = new JPanel();
        sizePanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED),
                                            "Pizza Size"));
        JPanel radioBoxesPanel = new JPanel();
        radioBoxesPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        radioBoxesPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));

        sizePizzaRButton = new JRadioButton[sizePizza.length];
        bGroupSize = new ButtonGroup();
        for (int i = 0; i < sizePizza.length; i++)
        {
            sizePizzaRButton[i] = new JRadioButton(sizePizza[i]);
            bGroupSize.add(sizePizzaRButton[i]);
            radioBoxesPanel.add(sizePizzaRButton[i]);
        }

        sizePanel.add(radioBoxesPanel);
        centerPanel.add(sizePanel, gbc);
        // Till this.

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        gbc.weighty = 0.7;

        /*
         * Above Constraints are for this part.
         */
        typePanel = new JPanel();
        typePanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED),
                                            "Pizza Type"));
        JPanel radioBoxesTypePanel = new JPanel();
        radioBoxesTypePanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        radioBoxesTypePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));

        typePizzaRButton = new JRadioButton[typePizza.length];
        bGroupType = new ButtonGroup();
        for (int i = 0; i < typePizza.length; i++)
        {
            typePizzaRButton[i] = new JRadioButton(typePizza[i]);
            bGroupType.add(typePizzaRButton[i]);
            radioBoxesTypePanel.add(typePizzaRButton[i]);
        }

        typePanel.add(radioBoxesTypePanel);
        centerPanel.add(typePanel, gbc);
        // Till this.

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 0.3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;

        processButton = new JButton("Process Selection");
        processButton.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                sBuilderOrder = new StringBuilder();
                sBuilderOrder.append("Pizza type : ");
                for (int i = 0; i < typePizza.length; i++)
                {
                    if (typePizzaRButton[i].isSelected())
                        sBuilderOrder.append(typePizzaRButton[i].getText());
                }

                sBuilderOrder.append("\n");
                sBuilderOrder.append("Pizza Size : ");

                for (int i = 0; i < sizePizza.length; i++)
                {
                    if (sizePizzaRButton[i].isSelected())
                        sBuilderOrder.append(sizePizzaRButton[i].getText());
                }

                sBuilderOrder.append("\n");
                sBuilderOrder.append("Toppings : ");
                /*
                 * I hope you can do this part yourself now :-)
                 */

                orderTArea.setText(sBuilderOrder.toString());
            }
        });
        centerPanel.add(processButton, gbc);

        footerPanel = new JPanel();
        footerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        footerPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your Order : "));
        orderTArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
        footerPanel.add(orderTArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        contentPane.add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        contentPane.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(footerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new PizzaLayout().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the same :

[image: PIZZALAYOUT]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Do yo mind if I ask your help for the action performed by the 'Process button' ?

Comment: Ahha, sure, but I do have my exams too, but will try to work out something for you, in small bits.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm working on it as well, but as I faced a lot of errors before I'm asking for your help in parallel. As you figured out from the OUTPUT this has to calculate and display particular information based on user entry. I'd be so thankful

Comment: Well if you look at the latest edit, you be able to figure out, how to go about this, hope you can do the remaining part yourself :-) , since you want to learn too. I had added `ButtonGroup` for `Type and Size` of the Pizza `JRadioButton`s and do check the `actionPerformed()` method for the `processButton`, that will give you the idea.

Comment: If something still beyond grasp, don't hesitate to ask, will try to sort that out tomorrow, now it's too late here, in the night.

Comment: thank you very much for your big help @Gagandeep Bali.
It's working now. but I think the code could be way more clean and brief.

Comment: Ohh yeah, as I was looking at your other question asked, I realized, in a hurry, I missed that you can use `Arrays` and put all `JCheckBoxes/JRadioButtons` inside an Array and compare their values with the `String` Array to make it brief.

Comment: Nice answer.  I think that UI might also be well suited to a `GroupLayout` though don't have time to develop that idea.

Comment: `main(String\u005B\u005D args)`  ..encoding?  ;) `frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);`  Ooh yeah!  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson : Seems like now a days you are a big fan of `GroupLayout`. Been tracking that thingy in many of your comments lately and answers :-) Thankx for the edits :-)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp : Hehe, cool, yeah `GridBagLayout` once conquered can give eye catching results.